# From within a Python function, how can I tell if it is being executed in the GPU with Numba or called regularly on the host / CPU?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

I have a function that sometimes call with Numba as a device function to execute on the GPU and sometimes I call directly from within regular Python on the host:

```
def process():
     # perform computation

process_cuda = cuda.jit(device=True)(process)
```

sometimes I call `process()` from directly from Python, and sometimes I invoke the `process_cuda` wrapper as a kernel with Numba.

My question, how can I tell, from within the `process` function, if it was called directly from Python or if it is executing as a Numba device function?

Comment: I am also interested in just finding if a function is being excecuted as a numba function (but on standard CPU not on a GPU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numba offers a function called `cuda.current_context()`, if the code is executed from a GPU the function return the current CUDA context otherwise it will return None when run using a CPU

So, we can initialize a variable in the `process()` to check if the code is executed from a CPU or GPU

```
def process():
    cuda_context = cuda.current_context()
    if cuda_context:
        return 'GPU'
    else:
        return 'CPU'
```

If there is anything I did wrong, please share it with me.

Comment: I think this looks promising - @ACarter can you test it? I don't have the setup now, and you added a bounty. Please let me know if you cannot and I'll set something up.

Comment: @EdyBourne I also don't have access to the right setup right now :/

Comment: OK no problem, I tested it - seems like this is working as intended. I will go ahead and accept it - thanks @Krishna Gunjan!

Answer (score -1):

I have found a makeshift method for doing so:

```
import inspect
from numba import cuda

caller_name = ''

def process():
  global caller_name
  caller_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
  caller_name = caller_frame.f_code.co_name
  a  =  2 + 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
  process_cuda = cuda.jit(device=True)(process)
  print(caller_name)

  process()
  print(caller_name)
```

It seems like the length of `caller_name` is always 0 when called by CUDA.

Comment: The OP explicitly states *"from within the `process` function"*. Your code check it from *outside* the function (and this is certainly non-standard btw). Global stores are not permitted from a CUDA function. If you run the CUDA kernel, then you will get the error *"Use of unsupported opcode (STORE_GLOBAL) found"*. It also does not work without the global access.